# Does too many If conditions harm website performance?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a Custom JS Variable with 12 If/else conditions.

if({{Click URL}}.match(...) && {{Click Classes}}.match(...)) !=null){
 return "";

and so on...

Does anyone have experience with website performance in such a case?

Thanks a lot.

Anton

Answer (score 1):

Nope. I didn't affects performance. Since using if-else you have skipped a block of codes but you code must be minimized as if-elseif-elseif-.......-elseif-else in a such manner. It could reduce the execution time.
didn't use if-else, if-else it may could affect you performance. Because, each time browser need to execute the if-else condition if the condition is not matched.

Comment: Hi @Tonmoy thanks for your reply. I used if/else if I just wrote it wrong in the question.

Comment: Hi there, I understand it. If you use a bunch of if/else over the same variable or similar purpose then go for if/elseif/....../elseif/else

Answer (score 0):

Twelve else/if conditions executed once would not make a browser sweat, especially since the code is only executes until the condition is met; after it returns the rest is ignored. `match`ing regular expressions is certainly more likely to cause performance issues.

However you are saying that this is used in a custom variable. So it might very well be that this is resolved multiple times per page (and the variable itself references other variables that need to be resolved every times), which would execute your if clauses and `match`es every time. This multiple execution of the code is the thing that might very well lead to performance issues.

Comment: Hello Eike, thanks for your reply! Any suggestions how to make it faster? For example I measure the clickstream on a few elements of our homepage. So I have a lot of if conditions, if Click ID contains CTA and so on and so forth. Did figure out a smarter method. Best regards, Anton